# Why appendChild() overrides createElement() if it was chained at the end of it?

Tags: javascript, chaining, appendchild, createelement

The Question:
I'm trying to understand why I can't chain the `appendChild()` method to `document.createElement()` like this:

```
var listItem = document.createElement('li').appendChild(text);
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="one"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
    <li id="two">pine nuts</li>
    <li id="three">honey</li>
    <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
</ul>
```

I know that this is the correct way to do it:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var txt = document.createTextNode('this is a text string');
var el = document.createElement('li');
el.appendChild(txt);
```

but why when I do this:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]; 
var text = document.createTextNode('I am the first generated list'); 
var listItem = document.createElement('li').appendChild(text); 
ul.appendChild(listItem);
```

it deletes the li element I formed and add the text ONLY to the ul item!
why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `appendChild` isn't designed to work that way. It could have been, but it wasn't. For it to work that way, `appendChild` would have to return a reference to the element on which it was called, but it doesn't; it returns the argument you pass to it.

> it deletes the li element I formed

No, it doesn't delete it; it never appends it, because `listItem` is not a reference to the element you created; it's the text node instead. From the [DOM3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107):

> **`appendChild`** (modified in DOM Level 3)
>
> Adds the node `newChild` to the end of the list of children of this node. If the `newChild` is already in the tree, it is first removed.
>
> Parameters
>
> - `newChild` of type `Node`
>
>   The node to add. If it is a DocumentFragment object, the entire contents of the document fragment are moved into the child list of this node
>
> Return Value
>
> - `Node`
>
>   **The node added.**

Note the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not deleting, the [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#Syntax) method return the appended child so in the second case, `listItem` holds the reference of text node which is appended.

```js
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var el = document.createElement('li');
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode('this is a text string'));
// or el.textContent = 'this is a text string';

ul.appendChild(el);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="one"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
  <li id="two">pine nuts</li>
  <li id="three">honey</li>
  <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
</ul>
```